# dnsmasq Адрес уже используется

Tags: linux, debian, настройка, настройки

Злравствуйте!

Возникла проблема при запуске компа - не стратует dnsmasq.
Особых манипуляций не выполнял.

выхлоп ls /etc/init.d

`acpid apache2 apt-cacher-ng bootlogs bootmisc.sh checkfs.sh 
checkfs.sh.lock checkroot-bootclean.sh checkroot.sh console-setup cron dbus dnsmasq exim4 halt hostname.sh hwclock.sh kbd keyboard-setup killprocs kmod motd mountall-bootclean.sh mountall.sh mountdevsubfs.sh mountkernfs.sh mountnfs bootclean.sh mountnfs.sh mysql networking nmbd procps rc rc.local rcS README reboot rmnologin rsyslog samba samba-ad-dc sendsigs single skeleton smbd squid3 ssh sudo tftpd-hpa udev udev-finish udhcpd umountfs umountnfs.sh umountroot urandom vsftpd webmin xinetd`

я так понимаю, что у меня идет конфликт портов(?) а вот кто и куда его конфликтует не знаю

**P.S.**: Система Debian 8 Jessie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас, скорее всего, идет конфликт с `udhcpd` , если dnsmasq работает как DNS и DHCP сервер. Кто слушает порты можно посмотреть так:

```
sudo netstat -pl
```

Попробуйте остановить udhcpd и запустить dnsmasq:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udhcpd stop
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
```

Посмотрите какой будет результат. А там или настраивать dnsmasq только на DNS, или оставить что-то одно.

Answer (score 0):

Простите за беспокойство ответ найден. Оказывается коллега пытался настроить ftp-сервер на этой машине. А у меня dnsmasq использует pxe-boot с собственным ftp-демоном. снес tftpd-hpa и vsftpd и все заработало =)

Всем спасибо за внимание